# FastApi: не отображается наименование заголовка в документации

Tags: python, python-3.x, fastapi

Необходимо что бы в документации отображались возможные параметры заголовков HTTP исходящие в ответ на GET запрос. Делаю это так:

```
@router.get('/hash_header',response_model=models.hash_out,tags=["use-hash"],responses={
        200: {
            "model": models.hash_out,
            "description": "Return has code",
            "headers": [
                {'name':"Secret-Code","description":"Secret code","type":"string"}
            ]
        }
})
```

Однако в документации наименование не отображается:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что делаю не так?

Answer (score 0):

Верная запись:

```
"headers": {
                "Secret-Code": {"description":"Secret code","type":"string"}
            }
```